# how to plot a single line with different types of line dash using bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to plot the line for a set of points. Currently, I have set of points as Column names X, Y and Type in the form of a data frame. Whenever the type is 1, I would like to plot the points as dashed and whenever the type is 2, I would like to plot the points as a solid line. 
Currently, I am using for loop to iterate over all points and plot each point using plt.dash. However, this is slowing down my run time since I want to plot more than 40000 points. 
So, is an easy way to plot the line overall points with different line dash type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could realize it by drawing multiple `line` segments like this 
(Bokeh v1.1.0)

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d, LinearAxis

line_style = {1: 'solid', 2: 'dashed'}

data = {'name': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'counter': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'score': [150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150],
        'age': [20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plot = figure(y_range = (100, 200))
plot.extra_y_ranges = {"Age": Range1d(19, 28)}
plot.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name = "Age"), 'right')

for i, g in df.groupby([(df.name != df.name.shift()).cumsum()]):
    source = ColumnDataSource(g)
    plot.line(x = 'counter', y = 'score', line_dash = line_style[g.name.unique()[0]], source = source)
    plot.circle(x = 'counter', y = 'age', color = "blue", size = 10, y_range_name = "Age", source = source)

show(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution does not if the values are non sequential. For example:  name =[ 'A', 'A' 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would be possible to add another axis on the right or top side for same plot line? For example, to plot at date of 1 with score 150 of age 15 years. ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But since it was not in your question I leave the implementation to you as an exercise. Here is [an example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html)

Comment: Thanks Tony. I have already tried something like this. But what I want is a single plot like a 3D point. I want point in 3D in to be represented in a 2d plane and 3rd axis on the top or right side of the graph.